# "Unsupported target for indexed assignment" with mypy, depending on type hinting moment with respect to assignment

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy, union-types

I'm trying to do some typing on my python code, and I got the following mypy error: "Unsupported target for indexed assignment"

On a simplified example, it amounts to the following code:

```
from pathlib import Path
from typing import (Literal, Mapping,
                    Optional, Union)

STRAND = Literal["+", "-"]
PATH = Union[str, Path]
fastq_files: Mapping[STRAND, Optional[PATH]] = {  # simultaneous annotation and assignment
    "+": None,
    "-": None}

reads_dir = Path("/tmp")
fastq_files["+"] = reads_dir.joinpath(  # mypy error
    "plus.fastq.gz")
fastq_files["-"] = reads_dir.joinpath(  # mypy error
    "minus.fastq.gz")
```

The error comes when replacing `None` with a `Path` in the dictionaries values.

How come values supposed to be of type `Optional[PATH]` cannot be replaced with values of type `Path`, given that `PATH` is `Union[str, Path]`?
I would have thought that a `Path` is compatible with `Union[str, Path]`, which in turn is compatible with `Optional[Union[str, Path]]`.

And why does the error disappear when I annotate the dict before assignment instead of annotating it at assignment time (see below)?

```
from pathlib import Path
from typing import (Literal, Mapping,
                    Optional, Union)

STRAND = Literal["+", "-"]
PATH = Union[str, Path]
fastq_files: Mapping[STRAND, Optional[PATH]]  # annotation before assignment
fastq_files = {
    "+": None,
    "-": None}

reads_dir = Path("/tmp")
fastq_files["+"] = reads_dir.joinpath(  # no mypy error
    "plus.fastq.gz")
fastq_files["-"] = reads_dir.joinpath(  # no mypy error
    "minus.fastq.gz")
```

The above shows that a `None` can be replaced by a `Path` in a "slot" with type `Optional[Union[str, Path]]`.

Does it mean that when I do the annotation at the same time as the assignment, the actual type is "reduced" to the strictest possible type compatible with the assigned value? (with the consequence that the "slot" gets a more restrictive type)

Answer (score 19):

The problem is that Mapping is supposed to be a read-only protocol -- if you check the [type hints for Mapping](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/master/stdlib/3/typing.pyi#L403), you can see it literally does not define a `__setitem__` method.

If you want to be able to mutate your mapping, you'll need to use Dict or MutableMapping instead.

Switching to using a TypedDict as suggested by the other answer would also work, since TypedDicts are assumed to be a subtype of Dict and so are inherently mutable.

Comment: Thanks for your explanations. However, if Mapping is supposed to be immutable, why does the second example pass mypy checking? The dictionary gets mutated there too.

Comment: @bli -- because the second assignment refines and narrows the type to a dict instead of keeping it a mapping. You can see this for yourself by adding a line that does `reveal_type(fastq_files)` before and after the assignment and re-running mypy.

Comment: By "second assignment", you mean `fastq_files = {"+": None, "-": None}`? I'm not sure what the line above with just a type annotation is in terms of Python. Is it a first assignment ?

Comment: @bli -- ah whoops, you're right. You have a variable annotation followed by a variable assignment, and there is no "second assignment". I meant to suggest adding `reveal_type(...)` lines around the `fastq_files = {"+": None, "-": None}` line -- which, as you note, is the first and only assignment of `fastq_files`.

Answer (score 1):

I think `TypedDict` solves this (weird) problem:

```
from pathlib import Path
from typing import (Literal, Mapping,
                    Optional, Union, TypedDict)

STRAND = Literal["+", "-"]
PATH = Union[str, Path]
FASTQ = TypedDict("FASTQ", {"+": Optional[PATH], "-": Optional[PATH]})

fastq_files: FASTQ = {
    "+": None,
    "-": None}

reads_dir = Path("/tmp")
fastq_files["+"] = reads_dir.joinpath("plus.fastq.gz")
fastq_files["-"] = reads_dir.joinpath("minus.fastq.gz")
```